# Unable to unit test an Angular directive that uses $window

Tags: javascript, angularjs, karma-runner, sinon

I've got a bunch of working unit tests for various Angular (1.4.7) directives, and I'm using Karma, Jasmine and Sinon for testing.

I'm trying to add a unit test for a new directive, which is the only directive I currently have that uses `$window` but I'm seeing a cryptic error in the console output:

> TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'this.proxy.toString')

This error is coming from sinon.js at line 2372.

I'm doing all the 'normal' things in a directive unit test such as creating a fake element that has the directive as an attribute:

```
testElement = document.createElement('div');
testElement.setAttribute('data-my-directive');
document.body.appendChild(testElement);
```

And compiling the directive:

```
$compile(testElement)($scope);
```

I'm using `$provide` to try mock the `$window` object:

```
module('app', function ($provide) {
    $provide.value('$window', { id: 'test' });
});
```

But as soon as I try to use `$window` in the file being tested, the error shown above is thrown.

As I say, I have a bunch of other unit tests for other directives, services and controllers working as expected, so everything appears to be setup correctly. It's just this particular test.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure if this is the same bug, but just a couple of days ago a fix to similar issue was got solved on sinon github:

https://github.com/sinonjs/sinon/pull/833

Fix contains lines:

```
var callStr = this.proxy ? this.proxy.toString() + "(" : "";
```

where the null check is one thing and several other lines.

This fix is at file `lib/sinon/call.js` in commit `7a18eb5`.

*I am not sure if this is same, because file is different and so is line, too. Still, this was so interesting that I would try latest sinon version and see if this gets fixed. It may be though, that similar error is in several parts of sinon, if the coder is for example same in both files.*

Comment: Perfect, I will try with a new version on Monday.

Comment: Sorry for the delay. I did some more work on this, it *wasn't* the version of Sinon, although that was a good call. I think the problem was that the code that used `$window` in the file under test was also inside a `$document.ready()` handler and previously I failed to stub this correctly. I'm going to mark this as the accepted answer because it's the only answer, and also because it made me think about all aspects of the code under test, not just the part using `$window` and that was invaluable. Thanks!